# Numba and the np.trapz function

Tags: python, numba

I am working on some Python code which involves a triple for-loop. This seems to quite significantly slow down the execution of my code. As I have to do a lot of simulations for my work, it would be a great help if this could be sped up somehow. To facilitate this, I looked at the Numba library. The following code snippet is the code I wish to speed up:

```
def opt_loop(m_hat_z,p_hat_tab, p_hat_tab2, f_hat_tab, x_grid):
    M, d = m_hat_z.shape
    for j in range(d):
        for l in range(M):
            sumint = 0
            for k in range(d):
                if k != j:
                    sumint += np.trapz(m_hat_z[:, k] * p_hat_tab2[l, :, j, k], x_grid[:, k])
            m_hat_z[l, j] = f_hat_tab[l, j] - sumint / (p_hat_tab[l, j])
    return m_hat_z
```

In the Numba description it says that it likes Numpy and it likes loops. So my code seems to be perfect for this. However, I get the following error when I try to run my code. The error message is much longer, but the important part seems to be the following:

```
No implementation of function Function(<function trapz at 0x106d44900>) found for signature:
 
 >>> trapz(array(float64, 1d, C), array(float64, 1d, A))
```

When I try to take the np.trapz - call out, it seems to work. However, when I create a function with only a np.trapz-call, the jit compilation of it seems to work...

```
import numpy as np
import time
from numba import jit

def opt_loop(m_hat_z,p_hat_tab, p_hat_tab2, f_hat_tab, x_grid):
    M, d = m_hat_z.shape
    for j in range(d):
        for l in range(M):
            sumint = 0
            for k in range(d):
                if k != j:
                    sumint += np.trapz(m_hat_z[:, k] * p_hat_tab2[l, :, j, k], x_grid[:, k])
            m_hat_z[l, j] = f_hat_tab[l, j] - sumint / (p_hat_tab[l, j])
    return m_hat_z

@jit
def opt_loop2(m_hat_z,p_hat_tab, p_hat_tab2, f_hat_tab, x_grid):
    M, d = m_hat_z.shape
    for j in range(d):
        for l in range(M):
            sumint = 0
            for k in range(d):
                if k != j:
                    sumint += np.trapz(m_hat_z[:, k] * p_hat_tab2[l, :, j, k], x_grid[:, k])
            m_hat_z[l, j] = f_hat_tab[l, j] - sumint / (p_hat_tab[l, j])
    return m_hat_z


M = 100
d = 15

m_hat = np.random.normal(size=(M,d))
p_hat_tab = np.random.normal(size=(M,d))
p_hat_tab2 = np.random.normal(size=(M,M,d,d))
f_hat_tab = np.random.normal(size=(M,d))
x_grid = np.linspace(np.zeros(d),np.ones(d),M)
t0 = time.time()
opt_loop(m_hat,p_hat_tab, p_hat_tab2, f_hat_tab, x_grid)
t1 = time.time()

# Run once to get compiled
opt_loop(m_hat,p_hat_tab, p_hat_tab2, f_hat_tab, x_grid)

# Time it
t2 = time.time()
opt_loop(m_hat,p_hat_tab, p_hat_tab2, f_hat_tab, x_grid)
t3 = time.time()

print("Normal: ", t1-t0)
print("Numba: ", t3-t2)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to use just Numba to speed up my Python program, but it didnt work as expected

Comment: the jit compilation of it never works, `@jit` just chooses not to jit compile it when it fails.

Comment: on the bright side, `np.trapz` is just a simple for loop, you can write it in two or three lines.

Comment: There is an implementation in the question marked as duplicate (and few points that might also be useful). You just need to transpose `x_grid` so to use it (operating on `x_grid[:, k]` is not efficient anyway). Note that calling `transpose` in Numpy is not enough and the array also needs to be copied since `transposed` only create a view.